# ERROR OCIEnvNlsCreate. Check ORACLE_HOME (Linux) env var or PATH (Windows) and or NLS settings, permissions, etc

Tags: linux, oracle, perl, dbi

I have perl script that uses DBD::Oracle to run a query and print the results. When I tried access through apache or the terminal I receive the same error.
ERROR OCIEnvNlsCreate. Check ORACLE_HOME (Linux) env var or PATH (Windows) and or NLS settings, permissions, etc.

So I set ORACLE_HOME environment variable and it works fine from the terminal but the apache throws the same. Any suggestions?

Comment: Try to find Perl library `Oracle.so` and execute `ldd` on it. Also check env variables ORACLE_HOME, and LD_LIBRARY_PATH. Such an error is often caused by confusion of Oracle drivers: Instant one vs. tick one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like your apache can't find ORACLE_HOME. Try setting ORACLE_HOME variable in the envvars file located in apache home dir:
export ORACLE_HOME=/path/to/oracle/home